# JOOQ update JSONB column with concat operator

Tags: jooq, jooq-codegen

I have a table with one of the column data type as JSONB and I'm trying to use the `JSONB concat (||)` operator  in postgresql to update the content for the jsonb column. Below is the sample plain sql query (insert / update example) which I want to convert to jooq.

```
create table foobar(id text primary key, address jsonb not null);

insert into foobar(id, address)
values ('1234', '["a", "b"]'::jsonb);


-- insert / update example
insert into foobar(id, address)
values ('1234', '["a", "b"]'::jsonb)
on conflict (id) DO UPDATE
set address = foobar.address || '["C"]'::jsonb
where foobar.id = '1234';

-- explicit update example
update foobar
set address = address || '["D"]'::jsonb
where id = '1234';
```

```
select * from foobar; 

Result for above query:

1234,"["a", "b", "C", "D"]"
```

I did see this [issue](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13950) for supporting `concatenation` is still open but want to check if there is any work around I can use.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is really about. Your title hints at this being about concatenation (you can always use [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/), if you're missing a feature). But it seems your *actual* question is about `ON CONFLICT`? Can you please edit your question and clarify?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My question is how can I convert the above insert/update example query to jooq

Comment: OK, what have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: I tried using the `concat` method like this



```
dslContent.insertInto(FOO_BAR)
.columns(FOO_BAR.ID, FOO_BAR.ADDRESS)
.values("1234", JSONB.value("["D"]"))
.onDuplicateKeyUpdate()
.set(FOO_BAR.ADDRESS, FOO_BAR.ADDRESS.concat(DSL.field("["D"]", JSONB.class)))
.execute();
```


But the `concat()` returns the `Field<String>` where as `set()` expects the `Field<JSONB>` as the second argument. So how can I use the concat operator so that it appends the new value to the existing value in json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always the [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) workaround in jOOQ, if you're missing support for some vendor specific functionality:

```java
Field<JSONB> jsonbConcat(Field<JSONB> f1, Field<JSONB> f2) {
    DSL.field("({0} || {1})", f1.getDataType(), f1, f2);
}
```